# Incorrect addition problem in assembly pi?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

So basically this is the program I am trying to run

```
.data

.balign 4

A : .word 4

B : .word 5

C : .word 2

D: .word 3

 

.text

.global main

main:

    ldr r0, addr_A
    ldr r0, [r0]
    ldr r1, addr_B
    ldr r1, [r1]
    ldr r2, addr_C
    ldr r2, [r2]
    ldr r3, addr_D
    ldr r3, [r3]
    mov r4, #4
    
    mul r0, r3
    mul r1, r2
    mul r2, r4
    add r3, r0, r1
    sub r3, r2
    bx lr
```

It's supposed to run the equation: D = D + 3A + 2B – 4C
But at this line:

```
add r3, r0, r1
```

Instead of giving me 25 it gives me 22
Im wondering what the problem is here?

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping with your debugger, thinking about what should be in what register at each stage, and comparing with what is actually there?

Comment: 22 is absolutely correct. What's the problem?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: `3 + 3*4 + 2*5 - 4*2` is 17, if I did that right.

Comment: @PeterCordes stage1: 4, 5, 2, 3, 4; stage2: 12, 10, 8, 22, 4; r3 is 22 at that line

Comment: The OP said the code produces 22, but that isn't what they want.  Explaining why the code produces 22 doesn't make it correct.  They also claim that `25` would be correct for that formula with those inputs, but actually it's 17, so both the code *and* their math are wrong, unless I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation is wrong.
And you should avoid multiplications wherever possible since it takes three cycles plus three cycles latency.

```
ldr     r0, addr_A
ldmia   r0, {r0, r1, r2, r3}

add     r3, r3, r0, lsl #1      // d = d + 2*a
sub     r1, r1, r2, lsl #1      // b = b - 2*c
add     r3, r3, r0              // d = d + a
add     r3, r3, r1, lsl #1      // d = d + 2*b
```

========================================================================

Below is how the equation gets compiled:

```
uint32_t foo(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c, uint32_t d)
{
    return d + 3*a + 2*b - 4*c;
}

foo
    SUB      r3,r3,r2,LSL #2
    ADD      r0,r0,r0,LSL #1
    ADD      r3,r3,r1,LSL #1
    ADD      r0,r3,r0
    BX       lr
```

Not exactly what I wrote in assembly, but same four instructions and same cycles.

Bottom line: As long as the assembly/disassembly above isn't a trivial thing for you, you should stay away from assembly.

Comment: `d + 3*a + 2*b - 4*c` isn't an equation to be solved, it's an a formula or expression to be evaluated.